# Cannot log in to Deluge Web UI?

Tags: login, web, javascript, bittorrent

I've set up deluge using this short guide: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient#WebUI

The deluge service IS running because I can navigate to my local server and see the log in box. However, when I enter the correct default password ("deluge") it simply flashes and shows me the box again. If I enter an incorrect password, I get an error message.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I can only recommend that you try running deluge directly on the command line, opposed to using the fork or an init script, so you can watch the output of the daemon. Hopefully it will tell you more about the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that my server's time wasn't synced properly (I was somewhere in 2003). I changed the time and synced with Ubuntu's ntp servers. Now deluge serves me a cookie which won't "expire".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the time on your box is correct, I just had this problem. Sync the time on your local server with `ntpdate pool.ntp.org` and try to log back in to Deluge WebUI.